# How to implement UITableView`s swipe to delete for UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

I just like to ask how can I implement the same behavior of UITableView`s swipe to delete in UICollectionView. I am trying to find a tutorial but I cannot find any.

Also, I am using PSTCollectionView wrapper to support iOS 5.

Thank you!

Edit:
The swipe recognizer is already good. 
What I need now is the same functionality as UITableView's when cancelling the Delete mode, e.g. when user taps on a cell or on a blank space in the table view (that is, when user taps outside of the Delete button).
UITapGestureRecognizer won't work, since it only detects taps on release of a touch.
UITableView detects a touch on begin of the gesture (and not on release), and immediately cancels the Delete mode.

Answer (score 18):

There is a simpler solution to your problem that avoids using gesture recognizers. The solution is based on `UIScrollView` in combination with `UIStackView`.

1. First, you need to create 2 container views - one for the visible part of the cell and one for the hidden part. You’ll add these views to a `UIStackView`. The `stackView` will act as a content view. Make sure that the views have equal widths with `stackView.distribution = .fillEqually`.
2. You’ll embed the `stackView` inside a `UIScrollView` that has paging enabled. The `scrollView` should be constrained to the edges of the cell. Then you’ll set the `stackView`’s width to be 2 times the `scrollView`’s width so each of the container views will have the width of the cell.

With this simple implementation, you have created the base cell with a visible and hidden view. Use the visible view to add content to the cell and in the hidden view you can add a delete button. This way you can achieve this:

[image: swipe to delete]

I've set up an [example project on GitHub](https://github.com/amerhukic/SwipeableCollectionViewCell-Example). You can also [read more about this solution here](https://www.amerhukic.com/swipeable-collection-view-cell).
The biggest advantage of this solution is the simplicity and that you don't have to deal with constraints and gesture recognizers.

Comment: Great solution. This approach makes it so that multiple cells can be swiped reveal the hiddenView at the same time. How would you enable single cell selection?  Setting scrollView.setContentOffset to zero does not seem to help.

Comment: Also, when implemented on a grid, deleting a cell accidentally trips a few of the reshuffled ones open (i.e. revealing the delete buttons). Any insights? Thanks!

Comment: @Plutovman when deleting a cell the collectionview reloads the cells and the cell that had the delete button opened will be reused. You need to remember the indexPath of the cell that is currently open and when a cell is dequeued you need to check if the indexPath matches the indexPath of the opened cell and open it by setting the content offset of the scrollview. When it gets deleted set the indexPath to nil.

Comment: You're absolutely correct.  Again, great job on an elegant solution.  It feels like UICollectionView should have this feature built in.

Comment: @AmerHukic Hey. Great solution. Yet, I am not sure what you meant by setting the indexPath to nil, mind if elaborating a bit? Cuz every time when a cell is deleted and reused, the view stayed at the hiddenview. I am trying to figure out how to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: @AmerHukic I actually figured out. Just set the scrollView contentOffset to 0 in the prepareForReuse method. Thanks

Answer (score 14):

Its very simple..You need to add a `customContentView` and `customBackgroundView` behind the `customContentView`.

After that and you need to shift the `customContentView`to the left as user swipes from right to left. Shifting the view makes visible to the `customBackgroundView`.

**Lets Code:**

First of all you need to add panGesture to your `UICollectionView` as

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.panThisCell))
        panGesture.delegate = self
        self.collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)

    }
```

Now implement the selector as

```
  func panThisCell(_ recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer){

        if recognizer != panGesture{  return }

        let point = recognizer.location(in: self.collectionView)
        let indexpath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: point)
        if indexpath == nil{  return }
        guard let cell = self.collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexpath!) as? CustomCollectionViewCell else{

            return

        }
        switch recognizer.state {
        case .began:

            cell.startPoint =  self.collectionView.convert(point, to: cell)
            cell.startingRightLayoutConstraintConstant  = cell.contentViewRightConstraint.constant
            if swipeActiveCell != cell && swipeActiveCell != nil{

                self.resetConstraintToZero(swipeActiveCell!,animate: true, notifyDelegateDidClose: false)
            }
            swipeActiveCell = cell

        case .changed:

            let currentPoint =  self.collectionView.convert(point, to: cell)
            let deltaX = currentPoint.x - cell.startPoint.x
            var panningleft = false

            if currentPoint.x < cell.startPoint.x{

                panningleft = true

            }
            if cell.startingRightLayoutConstraintConstant == 0{

                if !panningleft{

                    let constant = max(-deltaX,0)
                    if constant == 0{

                        self.resetConstraintToZero(cell,animate: true, notifyDelegateDidClose: false)

                    }else{

                        cell.contentViewRightConstraint.constant = constant

                    }
                }else{

                    let constant = min(-deltaX,self.getButtonTotalWidth(cell))
                    if constant == self.getButtonTotalWidth(cell){

                        self.setConstraintsToShowAllButtons(cell,animate: true, notifyDelegateDidOpen: false)

                    }else{

                        cell.contentViewRightConstraint.constant = constant
                        cell.contentViewLeftConstraint.constant = -constant
                    }
                }
            }else{

                let adjustment = cell.startingRightLayoutConstraintConstant - deltaX;
                if (!panningleft) {

                    let constant = max(adjustment, 0);
                    if (constant == 0) {

                        self.resetConstraintToZero(cell,animate: true, notifyDelegateDidClose: false)

                    } else {

                        cell.contentViewRightConstraint.constant = constant;
                    }
                } else {
                    let constant = min(adjustment, self.getButtonTotalWidth(cell));
                    if (constant == self.getButtonTotalWidth(cell)) {

                        self.setConstraintsToShowAllButtons(cell,animate: true, notifyDelegateDidOpen: false)
                    } else {

                        cell.contentViewRightConstraint.constant = constant;
                    }
                }
                cell.contentViewLeftConstraint.constant = -cell.contentViewRightConstraint.constant;

            }
            cell.layoutIfNeeded()
        case .cancelled:

            if (cell.startingRightLayoutConstraintConstant == 0) {

                self.resetConstraintToZero(cell,animate: true, notifyDelegateDidClose: true)

            } else {

                self.setConstraintsToShowAllButtons(cell,animate: true, notifyDelegateDidOpen: true)
            }

        case .ended:

            if (cell.startingRightLayoutConstraintConstant == 0) {
                //Cell was opening
                let halfOfButtonOne = (cell.swipeView.frame).width / 2;
                if (cell.contentViewRightConstraint.constant >= halfOfButtonOne) {
                    //Open all the way
                    self.setConstraintsToShowAllButtons(cell,animate: true, notifyDelegateDidOpen: true)
                } else {
                    //Re-close
                    self.resetConstraintToZero(cell,animate: true, notifyDelegateDidClose: true)
                }
            } else {
                //Cell was closing
                let buttonOnePlusHalfOfButton2 = (cell.swipeView.frame).width
                if (cell.contentViewRightConstraint.constant >= buttonOnePlusHalfOfButton2) {
                    //Re-open all the way
                    self.setConstraintsToShowAllButtons(cell,animate: true, notifyDelegateDidOpen: true)
                } else {
                    //Close
                    self.resetConstraintToZero(cell,animate: true, notifyDelegateDidClose: true)
                }
            }

        default:
            print("default")
        }
    }
```

Helper methods to update constraints

```
 func getButtonTotalWidth(_ cell:CustomCollectionViewCell)->CGFloat{

        let width = cell.frame.width - cell.swipeView.frame.minX
        return width

    }

    func resetConstraintToZero(_ cell:CustomCollectionViewCell, animate:Bool,notifyDelegateDidClose:Bool){

        if (cell.startingRightLayoutConstraintConstant == 0 &&
            cell.contentViewRightConstraint.constant == 0) {
            //Already all the way closed, no bounce necessary
            return;
        }
        cell.contentViewRightConstraint.constant = -kBounceValue;
        cell.contentViewLeftConstraint.constant = kBounceValue;
        self.updateConstraintsIfNeeded(cell,animated: animate) {
            cell.contentViewRightConstraint.constant = 0;
            cell.contentViewLeftConstraint.constant = 0;

            self.updateConstraintsIfNeeded(cell,animated: animate, completionHandler: {

                cell.startingRightLayoutConstraintConstant = cell.contentViewRightConstraint.constant;
            })
        }
        cell.startPoint = CGPoint()
        swipeActiveCell = nil
    }

    func setConstraintsToShowAllButtons(_ cell:CustomCollectionViewCell, animate:Bool,notifyDelegateDidOpen:Bool){

        if (cell.startingRightLayoutConstraintConstant == self.getButtonTotalWidth(cell) &&
            cell.contentViewRightConstraint.constant == self.getButtonTotalWidth(cell)) {
            return;
        }
        cell.contentViewLeftConstraint.constant = -self.getButtonTotalWidth(cell) - kBounceValue;
        cell.contentViewRightConstraint.constant = self.getButtonTotalWidth(cell) + kBounceValue;

        self.updateConstraintsIfNeeded(cell,animated: animate) {
            cell.contentViewLeftConstraint.constant =  -(self.getButtonTotalWidth(cell))
            cell.contentViewRightConstraint.constant = self.getButtonTotalWidth(cell)

            self.updateConstraintsIfNeeded(cell,animated: animate, completionHandler: {(check) in

                cell.startingRightLayoutConstraintConstant = cell.contentViewRightConstraint.constant;
            })
        }
    }

    func setConstraintsAsSwipe(_ cell:CustomCollectionViewCell, animate:Bool,notifyDelegateDidOpen:Bool){

        if (cell.startingRightLayoutConstraintConstant == self.getButtonTotalWidth(cell) &&
            cell.contentViewRightConstraint.constant == self.getButtonTotalWidth(cell)) {
            return;
        }
        cell.contentViewLeftConstraint.constant = -self.getButtonTotalWidth(cell) - kBounceValue;
        cell.contentViewRightConstraint.constant = self.getButtonTotalWidth(cell) + kBounceValue;

        self.updateConstraintsIfNeeded(cell,animated: animate) {
            cell.contentViewLeftConstraint.constant =  -(self.getButtonTotalWidth(cell))
            cell.contentViewRightConstraint.constant = self.getButtonTotalWidth(cell)

            self.updateConstraintsIfNeeded(cell,animated: animate, completionHandler: {(check) in

                cell.startingRightLayoutConstraintConstant = cell.contentViewRightConstraint.constant;
            })
        }
    }


    func updateConstraintsIfNeeded(_ cell:CustomCollectionViewCell, animated:Bool,completionHandler:@escaping ()->()) {
        var duration:Double = 0
        if animated{

            duration = 0.1

        }
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseOut], animations: {

            cell.layoutIfNeeded()

            }, completion:{ value in

                if value{ completionHandler() }
        })
    }
```

I have created a sample project [here](https://github.com/anishparajuli555/SwipeCollectionViewCell) in Swift 3.

It is a modified version of this [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/62435/make-swipeable-table-view-cell-actions-without-going-nuts-scroll-views).

Comment: Excellent example, this is the one you should be using in Swift 3 and 2017+

Comment: Feels quite different than UITableView. Also has glitches where multiple cells can be in swiped state. Then when tapping the cell that was first swiped, it crashes. I don't recommend to take and use this solution without properly fixing it. iOS 14 adds a native API, see `leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationProvider` and `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationProvider`.

Answer (score 13):

In the *Collection View Programming Guide for iOS*, in the section [Incorporating Gesture Support](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/IncorporatingGestureSupport/IncorporatingGestureSupport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH4-SW1), the docs read:

> You should always attach your gesture recognizers to the collection view itself and not to a specific cell or view.

So, I think it's not a good practice to add recognizers to `UICollectionViewCell`.

Answer (score 3):

I followed a similar approach to @JacekLampart, but decided to add the UISwipeGestureRecognizer in the UICollectionViewCell's awakeFromNib function so it is only added once.

UICollectionViewCell.m

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer* swipeGestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeToDeleteGesture:)];
    swipeGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [self addGestureRecognizer:swipeGestureRecognizer];
}

- (void)swipeToDeleteGesture:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipeGestureRecognizer {
    if (swipeGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        // update cell to display delete functionality
    }
}
```

As for exiting delete mode, I created a custom UIGestureRecognizer with an NSArray of UIViews. I borrowed the idea from @iMS from this question: [UITapGestureRecognizer - make it work on touch down, not touch up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15628133/uitapgesturerecognizer-make-it-work-on-touch-down-not-touch-up)

On touchesBegan, if the touch point isn't within any of the UIViews, the gesture succeeds and delete mode is exited.

In this way, I am able to pass the delete button within the cell (and any other views) to the UIGestureRecognizer and, if the touch point is within the button's frame, delete mode will not exit.

TouchDownExcludingViewsGestureRecognizer.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TouchDownExcludingViewsGestureRecognizer : UIGestureRecognizer

@property (nonatomic) NSArray *excludeViews;

@end
```

TouchDownExcludingViewsGestureRecognizer.m

```
#import "TouchDownExcludingViewsGestureRecognizer.h"
#import <UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>

@implementation TouchDownExcludingViewsGestureRecognizer

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (self.state == UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible) {
        BOOL touchHandled = NO;
        for (UIView *view in self.excludeViews) {
            CGPoint touchLocation = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:view];
            if (CGRectContainsPoint(view.bounds, touchLocation)) {
                touchHandled = YES;
                break;
            }
        }

        self.state = (touchHandled ? UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed : UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized);
    }
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed;
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed;
}


@end
```

Implementation (in the UIViewController containing UICollectionView):

```
#import "TouchDownExcludingViewsGestureRecognizer.h"

TouchDownExcludingViewsGestureRecognizer *touchDownGestureRecognizer = [[TouchDownExcludingViewsGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(exitDeleteMode:)];
touchDownGestureRecognizer.excludeViews = @[self.cellInDeleteMode.deleteButton];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:touchDownGestureRecognizer];

- (void)exitDeleteMode:(TouchDownExcludingViewsGestureRecognizer *)touchDownGestureRecognizer {
    // exit delete mode and disable or remove TouchDownExcludingViewsGestureRecognizer
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try adding a UISwipeGestureRecognizer to each collection cell, like this:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
             cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CollectionViewCell *cell = ...

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer* gestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(userDidSwipe:)];
    [gestureRecognizer setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
}
```

followed by:

```
- (void)userDidSwipe:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        //handle the gesture appropriately
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! However, UITableView`s swipe to delete allow user to cancel the delete upon touch of the screen. I cannot seem to implement that properly. Any suggestions?

Comment: The same way: create a UITapGestureRecognizer in the "handle the gesture appropriately" part.

Answer (score 2):

With iOS 14, you can use [`UICollectionViewLayoutListConfiguration`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionlayoutlistconfiguration) in conjunction with [`UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewcompositionallayout) to get this functionality natively for free, no custom cells or gesture recognizes needed.

If your minimum deploy target is >= iOS 14.x, this is probably the preferred method from now on, and it will also let you to adopt modern cell configuration with `UIContentView` and `UIContentConfiguration` to boot.

Answer (score 1):

There is a more standard solution to implement this feature, having a behavior very similar to the one provided by `UITableView`.

For this, you will use a `UIScrollView` as the root view of the cell, and then position the cell content and the delete button inside the scroll view. The code in your cell class should be something like this:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.addSubview(viewWithCellContent)
    scrollView.addSubview(deleteButton)
    scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
}
```

In this code we set the property `isPagingEnabled` to `true` to make the scroll view to stop scrolling only at the boundaries of its content. The layout subviews for this cell should be something like:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    scrollView.frame = bounds
    // make the view with the content to fill the scroll view
    viewWithCellContent.frame = scrollView.bounds
    // position the delete button just at the right of the view with the content.
    deleteButton.frame = CGRect(
        x: label.frame.maxX, 
        y: 0, 
        width: 100, 
        height: scrollView.bounds.height
    )

    // update the size of the scrolleable content of the scroll view
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: button.frame.maxX, height: scrollView.bounds.height)
}
```

With this code in place, if you run the app you will see that the swipe to delete is working as expected, however, we lost the ability to select the cell. The problem is that since the scroll view is filling the whole cell, all the touch events are processed by it, so the collection view will never have the opportunity to select the cell (this is similar to when we have a button inside a cell, since touches on that button don't trigger the selection process but are handled directly by the button.)

To fix this problem we just have to indicate the scroll view to ignore the touch events that are processed by it and not by one of its subviews. To achieve this just create a subclass of `UIScrollView` and override the following function:

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    let result = super.hitTest(point, with: event)
    return result != self ? result : nil
}
```

Now in your cell you should use an instance of this new subclass instead of the standard `UIScrollView`.

If you run the app now you will see that we have the cell selection back, but this time the swipe isn't working . Since we are ignoring touches that are handled directly by the scroll view, then its pan gesture recognizer won't be able to start recognizing touch events. However, this can be easily fixed by indicating to the scroll view that its pan gesture recognizer will be handled by the cell and not by the scroll. You do this adding the following line at the bottom of your cell's `init(frame: CGRect)`:

```
addGestureRecognizer(scrollView.panGestureRecognizer)
```

This may look like a bit hacky, but it isn't. By design, the view that contains a gesture recognizer and the target of that recognizer don't have to be the same object.

After this change all should be working as expected. You can see a full implementation of this idea [in this repo](https://github.com/rlaguilar/SwipeToDeleteCollectionView)