# Swipe to Delete UICollectionViewCell Programmatically

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, storyboard, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to follow the tutorial on this post: [How to implement UITableView`s swipe to delete for UICollectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270023/how-to-implement-uitableviews-swipe-to-delete-for-uicollectionview/46656495#46656495) exactly like it is, except for adding outlets from the storyboard, I have initialized everything (including my collection view) programmatically.

When I reach the screen containing the collection view, the swiping action to reveal the delete button under it does not take place. I have set the delegate method shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith to return true and have set up the cell like so:

```
import UIKit

class CustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    // Cell data
    var aLabel       : UILabel!
    var bLabel       : UILabel!
    var myImageView  : UIImageView!
    var myContentView: UIView!

    // Swipe to delete cell
    var contentViewLeftConstraint             : NSLayoutConstraint!
    var contentViewRightConstraint            : NSLayoutConstraint!
    var deleteButton                          : UIButton!
    var startPoint                            = CGPoint()
    var startingRightLayoutConstraintConstant = CGFloat()
    var swipeView                             : UIView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code

        backgroundColor = .clear

        myImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(
            x     : 15,
            y     : 10,
            width : frame.height - 20,
            height: frame.height - 20
        ))

        aLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(
            x     : myImageView.frame.maxX + 15,
            y     : 15,
            width : frame.width - 20 - myImageView.frame.maxX,
            height: 23
        ))

        bLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(
            x     : myImageView.frame.maxX + 15,
            y     : aLabel.frame.maxY,
            width : frame.width - 20 - myImageView.frame.maxX,
            height: 30
        ))

        swipeView = UIView(frame: CGRect(
            x     : contentView.frame.width - 60,
            y     : contentView.frame.minY,
            width : 60,
            height: contentView.frame.height
        ))
        deleteButton = UIButton(frame: swipeView.frame)
        deleteButton.backgroundColor = .red  // For visibility purposes
        swipeView.addSubview(deleteButton)

        myContentView = UIView(frame: contentView.frame)
        myContentView.addSubview(myImageView)
        myContentView.addSubview(aLabel)
        myContentView.addSubview(bLabel)

        contentView.addSubview(swipeView)
        contentView.addSubview(myContentView)

        // Pin the song data content view's left margin to the cell content view's left margin.
        contentViewLeftConstraint  = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item      : myContentView,
            attribute : .left,
            relatedBy : .equal,
            toItem    : contentView,
            attribute : .leftMargin,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant  : 0.0
        )
        contentViewLeftConstraint.isActive = true

        // Pin the song data content view's right margin to the cell content view's right margin.
        contentViewRightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item      : myContentView,
            attribute : .right,
            relatedBy : .equal,
            toItem    : contentView,
            attribute : .rightMargin,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant  : 0.0
        )
        contentViewRightConstraint.isActive = true
    }
}
```

My ViewController methods are the exact same as the ones in the tutorial. I printed out the pan movement like it is done in [Ray Wenderlich's original tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/62435/make-swipeable-table-view-cell-actions-without-going-nuts-scroll-views) and the pan gesture is behaving as expected. It's just that `myContentView` won't slide leftward to reveal the delete button. Maybe I am setting the constraints incorrectly?

Please help!